# How can the loop be stopped using "Enter" key in C?

Tags: c

**I want stop the loop when I will press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. But can't stop the loop.**

I need help to get rid of this problem.Thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int main()
{
    char ch;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter any character:\n");
        ch=getch();//any character can be entered 
    }while(ch!='\n');//stop when enter key is pressed

    printf("Enter key has been pressed");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `But can't stop the loop` or the loop is exiting _automatically_? :-)

Comment: BTW, `stdio.h` prototypes `getchar()`, not `getch()`....

Comment: Loop does not stop. Even, if I press enter key it continues without exiting.

Comment: I got it just now. It works when I use in do-while loop condition checking using '\r' in place of newline character '\n'. thanks @cremno for your link.

Comment: When using getchar() the loop does not work properly. @Sourav Ghosh.

Comment: `does not work properly` is not a valid problem description

Comment: Means if I use getchar()  it takes array of characters not single charcter until I press enter. After pressing enter it prints " Enter any character:"
Just like

Enter any charater:
abcde
Enter any charater:
Enter any charater:

Answer (score 0):

Use `getchar()` and change `char ch` to `int ch`.

```
int ch;
ch=getchar();
```

Loop will be stopped  as `enter` is pressed.